# Rails - Success callback is triggered on status: 422 response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I send ajax request:

```
$ ->
  $('#delete_product').dialog
    buttons:
      "Confirm": ->
        $(this).dialog('close')
        $.ajax
          url: '/products/' + $('#delete_product').data('current_product').attr('product_id'),
           type: 'POST',
           data: _method: 'DELETE',
           dataType: "json",
           success: ->
             $('#delete_product').data('current_product').fadeOut(200)
           error: ->
             alert('Error')
       "Cancel": ->
         $(this).dialog('close')
     autoOpen: false

   $('.delete-product').click ->
     current_product = $(this).closest('tr')
     $('#delete_product').data('current_product', $(current_product))

     $('#delete_product').dialog('open')
```

In controller I have:

```
def destroy
  render json: @product, status: 422
end
```

Firstly alert appears, then after clicking on OK button on the alert, the row is faded out. Seems that success callback was called after error one.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed ajax call to:

```
$.ajax(
  url: '/products/' + $('#delete_product').data('current_product').attr('product_id'),
  type: 'POST'
  data: _method: 'DELETE',
  dataType: "json"
  ).success ->
    $('#delete_product').data('current_product').fadeOut(200)
  .error ->
    alert('Error')
```

Now it works.